# Why does the returned array differ from the array that uses the return value in my program?

Tags: c, pointers, return

I have a program where I want to add a new element into an array of structs.
In my add function it seems to be working, but when I try to use it in the main function, it seems to differ from what's being originally returned.

I have my `main.c` like this:

```
int main(void) {
    Recept * receptek;
    int valasztas;
    int *hossz = 0; //A receptek száma.
    receptek = betolt("receptek.txt", &hossz);
    if (receptek != NULL) {
        menu();
        printf("Valasztott opcio: ");
        while(scanf("%d", &valasztas) == 1) {
            if(valasztas == 1) {
                Recept * uj = recept_felvesz(receptek, hossz);
                printf("%dTH VALUE HERE: %s\n", (int)hossz, uj[(int)hossz].nev);
                if(uj != NULL) {
                    printf("Recept sikeresen felveve.\n\n");
                    hossz = (int)hossz + 1;
                } else {
                    printf("Nem sikerult a receptet felvenni.\n\n");
                }
            } else if(valasztas == 2) {

                kiir(receptek, (int)hossz);
            } else if(valasztas == 6) {
                break;
            } else {
                system("cls");
                menu();
                printf("Ervenytelen opcio.\n\n");

            }
            printf("Valasztott opcio: ");
        }
    } else {
        printf("Nem sikerult betolteni a tarolofajlt!\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

And I store my add function (`recept_felvesz`) in a different `.h` file.

```
Recept* recept_felvesz(Recept* receptek, int* hossz) {
    printf("Hossz 1: %d", (int)hossz);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    char bekert_nev[30];
    char bekert_ot[300];
    printf("Add meg a recept nevet: ");
    if(fgets(bekert_nev, 30, stdin))
        bekert_nev[strcspn(bekert_nev, "\n")] = '\0';   //A \n karaktert kicseréli \0-ra
    printf("Add meg a recept osszetevoit: ");
    if(fgets(bekert_ot, 300, stdin))
        bekert_ot[strcspn(bekert_ot, "\n")] = '\0';     //A \n karaktert kicseréli \0-ra.
    system("cls");
    menu();

    Recept uj = {(int)hossz, bekert_nev, bekert_ot};
    receptek = (Recept*) realloc(receptek, ((int)hossz + 1) * sizeof(Recept));
    receptek[(int)hossz] = uj;

    if (receptek == NULL) return NULL;

    FILE *file = fopen("receptek.txt", "a");
    if (file == NULL) return NULL;

    fprintf(file, "\n%s;%s;", bekert_nev, bekert_ot);
    fclose(file);
    printf("\n%dTH VALUE HERE: %s\n", (int)hossz, receptek[(int)hossz].nev);
    return receptek;
}
```

Here is the buggy output at the moment:

```
15TH VALUE HERE: 32423
15TH VALUE HERE: ☺
Recept sikeresen felveve.
```

Why does the actual return value (`32423`) differ from what's being used in the `main` function(`☺`)?

Edit: structure `Recept` looks like this:

```
typedef struct Recept {
    int azonosito;
    char *nev;
    char *osszetevok;
} Recept;
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Recept`? It looks like you're storing pointers to local variables into `uj` (which then get copied into `receptek` and returned to the caller). Unrelated: Some of your NULL pointer checks are too late, as you'll have dereferenced the NULL pointer before the check.

Comment: I added the structure onto the bottom of the post

Comment: You use the pointer (`char *nev`) to the local variable `bekert_nev` in the function, which does not live any more.

Comment: I know it does not live out of the function but shouldn't it get stored in the return? Also, if it's the case, how could I solve this?

Comment: That looks weird: `receptek[(int)hossz] = uj;` If `hossz` really is a pointer, you might get huge values for your array. If it is not a pointer, why do you define it as `int*`?

Comment: "in a different .h file." I hope you don't define that function in a .h file. That would be really bad practice. Instead only put a declaration into the header and put the definition into a .c file.

Comment: BTW: You should keep in mind that the size of `int` and `int*` can differ. On many modern systems an `int` is 4 bytes while a pointer is `8 bytes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code memory of local variables `bekert_nev` and `bekert_ot` are used outside of the scope where they are defined (function `recept_felvesz`).  They are allocated on stack so after exit from function `recept_felvesz` their memory can be used by anyone else as it is considered unused. For example `printf` can store its internal variables in this memory block.

One way to fix this issue is to allocate `bekert_nev` and `bekert_ot` in global memory using `malloc` function:

```
char* bekert_nev = malloc(30);
char* bekert_ot = malloc(300);
```

Remember to free this memory with `free` function when you will destroy your main `receptek` array:

```
Recept* rec = receptek;
for( int i = 0; i < hossz; ++i) {
  free( rec->nev );
  free( rec->osszetevok );
  rec++;
}
```

Alternatively, you can put this arrays inside of your `Recept` struct and write directly into them

```
typedef struct Recept {
    int azonosito;
    char nev[30];
    char osszetevok[300];
} Recept;
```